# How to get the root directory of the project using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have defined the following fixture, which remove everything from the path after the root directory (`myapp`).

This is necessary as `pytest` changes the current directory (cwd), when executing the tests (why?).

However, this approach is not great, as it fails whenever more than one `myapp` entity exists in the path.

How can I get the path of the root directory using `pytest`?

```
def _get_project_root_path() -> str:
    return re.sub(r"/(myapp)(?:/.*)?", r"/\1", os.getcwd())


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def project_root_path():
    return _get_project_root_path()
```

Comment: I don't believe pytest changes the working directory, but it does run execute tests within `tmp` sub directories.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Config](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.Config) from `request` fixture

```
@pytest.fixture
def project_root_path(request):
    return request.config.rootpath
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to handle this via `pathlib` like so

```
from pathlib import Path

print(Path(__file__).parents[0])
```

Here, `__file__` refers to the file in which it's called, and `parents` returns an iterable of parent directories, the 0th index of which will be the file's immediate parent, and so on up the path until the last item (which is likely your current drive if you're on Windows, for example).

You can also use `Path.parent` to return the immediate parent of the given path, and you can call `parent` multiple times to traverse up the path, e.g.: `Path(__file__).parent.parent`.